# Generate Value for Class Property

Tags: swift

I'm trying to subclass UILabel and automatically generate a value for one of the properties, so that I can initialize with some values, and have others randomly generated.

For example, here I'd want to be able to create a new MyLabel, pass in a value for labelString and and have the value for labelNumber generated randomly.

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var labelString : String!
    var labelNumber : Int!

    init(frame: CGRect, labelString: String) {
        self.labelString = labelString
        self.labelNumber = createNumber()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func createNumber() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

I get the error "Use of 'self' in method call before super.init initializes self." Is there a way to fix this, or a better pattern to be using?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call instance methods from `init` until everything has been initialized.  One way to handle it is to make `createNumber` a `static` function which doesn't require the class to be initialized to be called:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var labelString : String!
    var labelNumber : Int!

    init(frame: CGRect, labelString: String) {
        self.labelString = labelString
        self.labelNumber = MyLabel.createNumber()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    static func createNumber() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

Another way to handle it is to move the initialization of `labelNumber` after the call to `super.init`.  This works because `labelNumber` is an *Optional* and thus is initially given the value of `nil` which meets the requirement that all properties of the subclass `MyLabel` are initialized before calling the `init` of the superclass.

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var labelString : String!
    var labelNumber : Int!

    init(frame: CGRect, labelString: String) {
        self.labelString = labelString
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.labelNumber = createNumber()
    }

    func createNumber() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

Comment: By the way, is there a particular reason you want `labelString` and `labelNumber` to be *Optional*s?  What reason would you have for them to be `nil` and reading them in that case would crash since you've made them *Implicitly Unwrapped Optional*s.

Comment: Making the parameters optionals came out of following another lesson (blindly), but in my case it's not necessary. So the second solution doesn't work here once they're not optionals, but the Static function is perfect! Thanks for the helping me get un-stuck.

Comment: You're welcome. You can make the second solution work with non-optionals by declaring it as `var labelNumber = 0`